# maya.api.openMaya setWeight not calling right version of function

Tags: python, maya, skinning

I'm not including the supplementary files that I use to track maya nodes, so if you see attr, just know that it's a way to track dags/MObjects as well as pass variables and find paths to and from attributes of those tracked nodes. The Polygon and PolygonShape are similar classes that inherit that node tracking method but are specific to those types of nodes. The code for them was further up in this file, but I'm excluding the code so as to not make this any longer than it needs to be. Suffice to say, they just tracks the polygon dag and the polygonShape MObj.

Here's my problem.

```
# Error: line 1: TypeError: file D:/Libraries/My Documents/maya/scripts\toolbox\Shapes.py line 332: an integer is required #
```

The line 332 is the setWeight line at the bottom.

Using this code, I can get the weights and break them apart by their verts seemingly fine, but when I try to setWeights, it says that it needs an int variable. That int variable refers to a vert by vert version of the setWeight method. For some reason it's not accepting the variables I'm submitting and reverting to the wrong method. I've checked all the types going into the method. They are correct. I checked that the length of the influences and the length of the weights were correct. Since they're the right type and right length, I'm left to assume that it's something to do with the self.vertexComp, but that MObject worked correctly for the get, and I've seen versions of this setWeights that used the exact same method.

Can anyone look at this and see what is causing the setWeight to get that error:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import Attributor as attr #custom package to interact with nodes
import maya.api.OpenMaya as om
import maya.api.OpenMayaAnim as omAnim

class skinCluster(attr.node):
    outputGeometry = attr.connection("outputGeometry")

    def getInfl_IDs(self,dagObj=False,pathFirst=False):
        infDags = self.skinFn.influenceObjects()
        infIds = {}
        for x in xrange(len(infDags)):
            infPath = attr.joint(nodeName=infDags[x].fullPathName()) if dagObj else infDags[x].fullPathName()
            infId = int(self.skinFn.indexForInfluenceObject(infDags[x]))
            if pathFirst:
                infIds[infPath] = infId
            else:
                infIds[infId] = infPath
        return dict(infIds)
        # Returns something like {0:"joint1",1:"joint2"}
        # useful for figuring out what list indexes to edit with weight tools

    def __init__(self, nodeName=None, tracker=None, vertices=None, shapeNode=None):
        if not nodeName and vertices:
            nodeName = polygonShape(nodeName=vertices[0]).inMesh["in"][0]
        self.initialize(nodeName=nodeName, tracker=tracker)
        self.polygon = polygon(nodeName=self.outputGeometry["out"][0])
        self.shapeNode = shapeNode if shapeNode else polygonShape(nodeName=self.polygon.shapeNodes[0].path)
        self.skinFn = omAnim.MFnSkinCluster(self.tracker.obj)
        self.vertexComp = om.MFnSingleIndexedComponent().create(om.MFn.kMeshVertComponent)

    def getWeights(self, vertices=None):
        vertWeights = self.skinFn.getWeights(self.polygon.tracker.dag, self.vertexComp)
        weights = list(vertWeights[-2])
        infCount = vertWeights[-1]
        weights = [weights[x:x+infCount] for x in range(0,len(weights),infCount)]
        dicty = {}
        for i, weight in enumerate(weights):
            if not vertices or i in vertices:
                dicty.update({i:weight})
        return dicty
        # returns a vert weight list
        # {0:[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], 1:[etc..]}

    def setWeights(self,values=None,normalize=True):
        vertices = values.keys() #gets all the verts that are going to be edited
        oldWeights = self.getWeights(vertices) #gets vert weights for undo
        oldValues = []
        newValues = []
        influences = self.getInfl_IDs().keys() # gets the influence indices
        for vert in vertices:
            oldValues += oldWeights[vert]   # combine weights into a list
            newValues += values[vert]  # combines the new weights to a list
        self.skinFn.setWeights(self.polygon.tracker.dag, self.vertexComp,
                               om.MIntArray(influences), om.MDoubleArray(newValues),
                               normalize=normalize, oldValues=om.MDoubleArray(oldValues))
```

While printing to double check types, this was the output:

```
<type 'OpenMaya.MDagPath'>
<type 'OpenMaya.MObject'>
<type 'OpenMaya.MIntArray'>
<type 'OpenMaya.MDoubleArray'>
<type 'bool'>
<type 'OpenMaya.MDoubleArray'>
```

Source Materials:

- ### https://gist.github.com/utatsuya/a95afe3c5523ab61e61b

  http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/api/class_m_fn_skin_cluster.html#52071d6c77ca374a4c8723f0c63e90e5

Found a post with a similar issue, but it didn't appear to help. Maybe someone else will notice why their solutions work and what I'm missing.

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python_inside_maya/0N8-Y70rGTQ

Comment: reviewing code. Wondering if maybe the problem is that the MDoubleArray doesn't have [in]  count  the number of elements in the src array. I don't know what that does exactly, but the getWeight has the number of influences at the end of its MDoubleArray, so maybe I need to add that to my setWeight.

Comment: I believe I'm onto the issue, but I hit a snag. I need to create an unsigned int to pass to the MDoubleArray and another one for the MIntArray, but python doesn't support that. I can supposedly create an MScriptUtil() from the maya api that can create these, but I can't seem to do self.util = om.MScriptUtil() to initialize it. Says it doesn't exist. Anyone know how to create an MScriptUtil?

Comment: Found that I could create an om.MUintArray and pass values through it to get the unsigned int, but now the om.MIntArray is giving me an error when I do om.MIntArray([], unsigned int). Says it requires an integer.   ...which is the only thing I'm passing to it, but I think I can work around it by initializing the array first and then adding the elements. But, if anyone knows what's going on, still looking for help to shave some time off of this task.

Comment: No luck. The MDoubleArray didn't require the unsigned int. I thought I needed that because the get weight gave an unsigned int in the return statement (MDoubleArray([...]),7L), but I misread some of the documentation. The MDoubleArrays seem to be created correctly. I have no idea why it's not working at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found with the maya.api.OpenMayaAnim setWeight function is that it's not undoable. You have to do extra steps to make it so it can be undone, and that's a pain. So instead I created something that fetches the getWeight values and uses the skinPercent command to set them.

```
@property
def weights(self):
    vertWeights = self.skinFn.getWeights(self.polygon.tracker.dag, self.vertexComp)
    weights = list(vertWeights[-2])
    infCount = vertWeights[-1]
    weights = [weights[x:x + infCount] for x in range(0, len(weights), infCount)]
    dicty = {}
    for i, weight in enumerate(weights):
        dicty.update({i: weight})
    # returns {vert1:[weightValue0,weightValue1,weightValue2..],vert2:[etc..]}
    # weight list index corresponds to influences from self.getInfl_IDs(), so it's easy to iterate weights using the index.
    return dicty

@weights.setter
def weights(self, values):
    #Will only set verts sent to it. Uses same data structure as get
    influences = self.getInfl_IDs()
    for vert, weights in values.iteritems():
        tempy = []
        for i, value in enumerate(weights):
            tempy += [(influences[i],value)]
        cmds.skinPercent(self.path, self.shapeNode.getVertName(vert), transformValue=tempy)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much a solution, but a work around. I found that if I took out the oldValues from the setWeight it suddenly works.

```
def setWeights(self,values=None,normalize=True):
    vertices = values.keys()
    oldWeights = self.getWeights()
    newWeights = dict(oldWeights)
    for key, value in values.iteritems():
        newWeights[key] = value
    oldValues = []
    newValues = []
    influences = self.getInfl_IDs().keys()
    intArray = om.MIntArray()
    intArray.copy(influences)
    for vert in oldWeights.keys():
        oldValues += oldWeights[vert]
        newValues += newWeights[vert]
    oldValues = om.MDoubleArray(oldValues)
    newValues = om.MDoubleArray(newValues)
    self.skinFn.setWeights(self.polygon.tracker.dag, self.vertexComp, intArray, newValues, normalize=normalize)
```

So if anyone knows why the oldValues is causing it to call the wrong method, please let me know.

Comment: I think that's the correct way to do it. You're using 
`import maya.api.OpenMayaAnim as omAnim`
and the documentaiton you linked is from the old maya.OpenMayaAnim.

The newer OpenMayaAnim returns the values rather than setting them in-place, so if you want the old values back, you need to do
`oldValues = self.skinFn.setWeights(self.polygon.tracker.dag, self.vertexComp, intArray, newValues, normalize=normalize)`

Comment: A couple of other things I've found, after trying this a bit more myself:  <br/>
<br/>
You have to use maya.api.OpenMaya type variables. You can't use a list of ints or floats for the influences or weights. This is in contrast to a lot of the API 2.0 functions where native python types are fine.  <br/>
<br/>
The exception  <br/>
`# TypeError: an integer is required #`  <br/>
seems to be raised no matter what you get wrong.